# c# Application cannot access the internet if I am connected to a VPN

Tags: c#, vpn

I am working on an application that needs constant internet connectivity in order to function according to specifications.

The problem that I am facing is that if I connect to a VPN then the application is unable to access the internet at all.

Here is a part of the code where I try to check whether the server is reachable or not:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        //var networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("shumais", "password");
        //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("192.168.0.61", 8080) { Credentials = networkCredentials };
        //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("192.168.0.61", 8080);
        //client.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(); 

        IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Proxy = proxy;

        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(WebUrls.URL_BASE_REQUEST))
        {
            _isServerReachable = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    _isServerReachable = false;
}
```

I have got the code working with/without proxies and now just need to get the application to work when I am connected to any VPNs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the code because you're setting up Network Credentials but then using the Default Credentials for the proxy and the client. Can you look into this and see if it helps at all?

Comment: Well thats because the codes is in development and I was testing with various configurations... Default Credentials, Network Credentials, No Credentials etc.. The networkCredentials line should be commented out for the current code. I will edit it. And, no, it didnt help.

Comment: Good! I was hoping you would say that.. I have something for you since you're intentionally trying to make this request using the default credentials. Check my answer (eta. 1 minute)

Comment: Hmmm, well I am doing that for the Proxy server that was configured for the test environment at work. If we disregard all of that then the issue is simply that the application is unable to access the internet when I have connected to a VPN. I think that the VPN and Proxy Server are two independent Use Cases and my understanding is that their solutions are also going to be "completely" different, I might be wrong though. :) So, I will check out your solution and see how that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Microsoft PPTP VPN, you need to uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network" in the TCP/IPv4 advanced settings for the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to access the site with the default network credentials, make sure to add the default proxy to the app.config file, and add a cookie container (seriously sounds stupid but it looks like it's helping other people out too).

Check out my answer to this post: [How to use IE proxy server settings and its credentials in .Net Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984755/how-to-use-ie-proxy-server-settings-and-its-credentials-in-net-application/22202845#22202845)